# Generate URL from FileId in DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, .net, file, hyperlink, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to create a link to a file to put into an email when a user completes their upload. How do you do this in DotNetNuke? The file is saved correctly and I have all the file information but I cannot find a way to generate a link to any file that I could share in an email or post elsewhere online.
I looked at LinkClick as used in the Documents module but that didn't lead anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just need to call [`Globals.LinkClick`](http://dnn.byteblocks.com/dnnapi/html/Overload_DotNetNuke_Common_Globals_LinkClick.htm) and pass in `"FileID=" + fileId` as the "link" (first parameter).

Comment: Thanks. That was stupid easy. Why is there no good DotNetNuke documentation for things like this?

Comment: They've been doing better on documentation, but there's still a lot left unsaid.  They'd probably suggest that you add some content to http://wiki.dotnetnuke.com if you find yourself missing it.  But I definitely agree, I'm looking through the source code more often than not to figure out the hows and whys of DNN.